# MySQL SELECT via xref table plus get count of another table's rows

Tags: mysql

Sorry about the title. I'm not sure how to properly describe the problem.

I have four tables, tables A, B, X and D. A and B have a many-to-many relationship so I'm using X as the link table.

Here's the structure:

[image: DB Structure]

Assuming all I have is an ID corresponding to a row in table A, I want to select the rows in table B that match up with that ID plus a count of all rows in table D that have the same `b_id`. Eh, I suck at explaining in words.

Here's what I would like (**all I have to search with is an ID which corresponds to a row in table A** -- let's just say I have an "A"):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| b.id | (A COUNT of how many rows in D have a b_id = b.id) |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |                       20                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  4   |                       12                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, according to the above results, this particular "A" has two "B"s. One of those "B"s has 20 "D"s and the other has 12 "D"s.

How can I write a single query to give me the results I'm after (again, all I'm searching with is an ID in table A)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.id, COUNT(1)
  FROM a,x, b,c
    WHERE a.id = <YOUR_ID_FOR_A>
     AND a.id = x.id 
     AND  x.b_id = b.id
     AND b.id = d,b_id
     GROUP BY b.id
```

If the table x has b_id entries that must exist in table b then you can by pass one join and use the query below:

```
SELECT b.id, COUNT(1)
  FROM a,x,c
    WHERE a.id = <YOUR_ID_FOR_A>
     AND a.id = x.id 
     AND  x.b_id = d,b_id
     GROUP BY b.id
```

EDIT: Corrected the typo, changed . to , as column separator.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be an error though: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(1) FROM a, x, c WHERE a.id = 1' at line 1`

Comment: There was a typo Fixed. Also note that I have left <YOUR_ID_FOR_A> as a gap filler for the id you want to pass.

Comment: Thanks! It appears to work now. I had to make a couple of changes though (changed `FROM a,x,c` to `FROM a,b,x,d` and `a.id = x.id` to `a.id = x.a_id` and replaced the comma on LINE 5 with a period).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT A.id, B.id, COUNT(B.id) AS cnt
FROM A
INNER JOIN X ON A.id = X.a_id
INNER JOIN B ON X.b_id= B.id
INNER JOIN D ON B.id = D.b_id
GROUP BY B.id
```